# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when trying to alter certain elements of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, typeerror

I have a list of 2 by n arrays of x and y coordinates.

```
old: [array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])]
```

I am trying to shift the y-coordinates, the second row of each array, by a certain value 'shift'. However, when I try to do this by the method below, I get the an error:

> "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when trying to alter certain elements of a list of arrays."

```
import pylab


    def shiftY(old,shift):
        new = list([])

        for i in arange(len(old)):
            y = old[i][1,:] + shift
            newItem = array([old[:,0],y])
            new.append(newItem)

        return new

    old = list()
    old.append(arr

ay([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
old.append(array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60]]))
shift =3 
new=shiftY(old,shift)
print(new)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/tald574/testShifty.py", line 25, in <module>
    new=shiftY(old,shift)
  File "C:/Users/tald574/testShifty.py", line 15, in shiftY
    newItem = array([old[:,0],y])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong as `newItem` is not even supposed to be a list, it should be a 2D array. Would appreciate it if someone can tell me what I do wrong an how to fix it.

Thanks.

Edit:
The expected outcome of this test would be,

```
new:[array([[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]), array([[10, 20, 30], [43, 53, 63]])]
```

Comment: I think there is a line break in the line starting with `old.append(arr` which should not be there

Comment: `old[:,0]` is not correct python syntax. what is the semantics of that thing?

Comment: you probably want `newItem = array(old[i][:,0]),y]`

Comment: In python a list is essentially an array(c/c++)

Comment: there are syntax errors all over this code. all needs reworking. Right question needs to be asked.

Comment: Could you guys be a bit more specific w.r.t. the syntax errors. I have no syntax errors when running the code and would appreciate any non-critical syntax rules that I don't know. I have taught the python I know to myself, so I may have missed of the proper syntax lectures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when copying a python list to a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884527/how-can-i-prevent-the-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-tuple-when-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the commas in the list slicing notation. `array[:,i]` is parsed as `array[:t]`, where `t = ,i` is a tuple. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) for a rundown of list slicing.

Tuples are [defined by commas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), not parentheses.

In your case, replace the lines

```
y = old[i][1,:] + shift
newItem = array([old[:,0],y])
```

with

```
y = old[i][1:] + shift
newItem = array([old[:0],y])
```

Comment: Both options work, but neither solves the problem at hand.
I agree that the second option is a bit more elegant, but in my view it hides the elements it accesses. But that may just be because I am fairly new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I feel stupid now.

I have been working on this for way too long and off course I figure out the answer within 15 minutes of posting this question.

I made two mistakes in the assignment of 'newitem'.
instead of

```
newItem = array([old[:,0],y])
```

I should have used:

```
newItem = array([old[i][0,:],y])
```

That is, I need to access the appropriate item in the list, old[i] rather than old.
And I need to access the appropriate item in the array old[i][0,:] rather than old[i][:,0].
Rookie mistake, I hope this helps someone else.

Edit, oh wow, only now see all the comments and answers on my question, thanks guys, I took so long because I incorporated this into my actual project, rather than just the test script. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `,` is placed instead of `:`.

Replace the comma with colon.

Below is the correct syntax of the sublist creation from the list.

```
list_name[start_index:end_index]
```