# Populating new list when each element is an array

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a new list of data from some existing data. Currently though I am having the problem where each element of my new list is being saved as its own single-element list. I can't see why this is.  My code is currently something like:

```
old_data = np.reshape(old_data, (49210, 1)) #Reshape into 1D array
new_data = [None] #Create empty list to be filled
max_value = np.nanmax(old_data)
threshold = 0.75 * max_value #Create threshold to be used as condition for new list.

for x in range(len(old_data)):
    if old_data[x] > threshold:
        new_data.append(old_data[x])
```

Please note that `old_data` was stored as a 2D array, which is why I have included that `np.reshape` command at the start.

As I said above, each time the condition is fulfilled the value is stored as a new element in `new_data`, but the element is an array of type float32 with size (1,). So `new_data` has ended up being an array of arrays. I'm not sure why this is. I would really just like a regular array/list output from this so that new_data is tractable. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: @JakobVinkas thank you, that's very useful for me to know as I am new to Python (clearly). I am actually getting the same result. I suspect then that my issue must be with how I have stored/structured  `old_data`. I will investigate and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have the data but this might work:

```
old_data = np.reshape(old_data, (49210, 1)) #Reshape into 1D array
threshold = np.nanmax(old_data) #Create threshold to be used as condition for new 
new_data = [element for element in old_data if element > threshold]
```

List comprehension is both faster and much prettier to use instead of for loops with append.

In case you have ended up with a array of arrays you might want to try the following instead:

```
old_data = np.reshape(old_data, (49210, 1)) #Reshape into 1D array
threshold = np.nanmax(old_data) #Create threshold to be used as condition for new 
new_data = [element[0] for element in old_data if element[0] > threshold]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see, you are using numpy library to flatten a 2D array to a 1D array.

What you can do is flatten your 2D array into a 1D array and then append your old list to your new list as you would like.

To flatten a 2D array to a 1D array -

```
import numpy as np 
  
ini_array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]) 
   
# Multiplying arrays 
result = ini_array1.flatten() 
  
# printing result 
print("New resulting array: ", result)
```

The result will be your old 2D array as a normal 1D array or a python list which you can append to your new list to get your final list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both @JakobVinkas and @Innomight. I've tried both solutions and both have worked. I'm still slightly confused as to why I was originally getting this problem but I will just read up on that I guess.

For anyone who may have come across this question later I have implemented what Jakob suggested using `element[0]` as my solution.

Also I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925698/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-tuple-when-trying-to-alter-certain/33925955) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to be a good explanation of what is fundamentally happening here in the first place.