# Possible to use list comprehension with condition on second list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

This is a follow on from [a previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63407308/populating-new-list-when-each-element-is-an-array) about populating a new list element-wise based on a condition. I am now wondering if I can create a second new list that is populated still conditionally on the first with list comprehension. Originally I had:

```
 old_list1 = np.reshape(old_data, (49210, 1)) #Reshape into 1D array
 new_list1 = [None] #Create empty list to be filled
 max_value = np.nanmax(old_list1)
 threshold = 0.75 * max_value #Create threshold to be used as condition for new list.
```

...then, as per the answer to my previous question, I can create a new list based on `threshold` as:

```
new_list1 = [element[0] for element in old_list1 if element[0] > threshold]
```

I have another list, `old_list2`, that is the same length as `old_list1`.  Can I create `new_list2` using list comprehension that is still conditional on the matching element of `old_list1` meeting the `threshold` condition?

That is, is this:

```py
j = 0
for i in range(len(old_list1)):
    if old_list1[i] > threshold:
         new_list1[j] = old_list[i]
         new_list2[j] = old_list2[i]
         j += 1
```

...possible with list comprehension?

Thank you as always!

Comment: List comprehensions are for only for building lists, but your `for` loop  mutates two existing lists, which is not the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can either use list comprehension in conjunction with `zip` to associate the items.  Or, if you already have the data in `numpy` arrays, just use conditional indexing:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([10, 1, 9, 8])
threshold = 0.75 * np.nanmax(data1)  # 7.5 in this example

data2 = np.array([500, 200, 300, 100])

# using list comprehension and zip
new_data = [t[1] for t in zip(data1, data2) if t[0] > threshold]
print(new_data)   # [500, 300, 100]

# using numpy's conditional indexing...
new_data2 = data2[data1 > threshold]
print(new_data2)  # [500 300 100]
```