# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, csv, numpy

fvecs = []

```
for line in open(filename):
    stats = line.split(',')
    labels.append(int(stats[0]))
    fvecs.append([float(x) for x in stats[5,6,12,27,29,37,39,41]])
```

I have a big csv. file that I am using as a dataset containing 43 columns and hundreds of rows, I am attempting to extract specific columns to be used as individual records and I can't seem to work this out. The error is caused by the final line of code and produces the error message in the title, it works perfectly when the range is set to, stats[30:38] for example.

I have tried storing the required columns in a separate array and calling it like stats[requiredcolumns] but this produces the same error.

I have considered using pandas but this is just a small snippet of code from a much larger program, which all functions correctly, and the implementation of pandas would require a complete overhaul of the full program which is not possible due to time constraints.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `stats` is just a list, not a Numpy array. As a list, it doesn't support Numpy's advanced indexing features. If all items in stats are numbers, you could convert it into a Numpy array first, before attempting the advanced indexing. Even so, the syntax you're using for indexing won't work like this.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not all numbers, so you don't think this will work at all the way it currently is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when copying a python list to a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884527/how-can-i-prevent-the-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-tuple-when-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have few columns, you can try this:

```
for line in open(filename):
    stats = line.split(',')
    labels.append(int(stats[0]))
    fvecs.append([float(x) for x in stats[5],stats[6],stats[12],stats[27], stats[29], stats[37], stats[39], stats[41]])
```

This code will return a list of lists; otherwise, the first comment is right about indexing and NumpPy.

Comment: `indices = [5, 6, 12, 27, 29, 37, 39, 41]; fvecs.append([float(stats[index]) for index in indices])` will save you a fair amount of typing, and is easier to extend to arbitrarily many columns.