# hi, everyone I am new to machine learning and was trying to make my first neural network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

## Test with Handwritten Digits

```
import imageio
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime as t
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
    import cv2
     import os
      import glob
   img_dir = "C:\\Users\\fitsu\\Desktop\\14 treangle"
     data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
   files = glob.glob(data_path)
   images = []
 for f1 in files:
     img = cv2.imread(f1)
     images.append(img)
     gray = rgb2gray(img)
     gray = gray.reshape(1, img_rows, img_cols, 1)
     gray /= 255
     gray = np.dot(images[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
     plt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
     plt.show()
     from keras.models import load_model
     model = load_model("first_test")
     # predict digit
      prediction = model.predict(gray)
     print(prediction.argmax())
```

> TypeError:''' File "", line 25, in
>   
>       gray = np.dot(images[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: File "<ipython-input-60-8728d3387446>", line 25, in <module>
    gray = np.dot(images[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent the TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple when copying a python list to a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884527/how-can-i-prevent-the-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-tuple-when-c)

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message. Why are you importing a module inside of a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import imageio
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime as t
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import cv2
import os
import glob
img_dir = ('.') # Enter Directory of all images 
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
images = []
for f1 in files:
  img = cv2.imread(f1)
  images.append(img)
  images2 = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
  images2 = np.expand_dims(images2,axis=3)
  #images2 = np.array(img)
  gray = rgb2gray(images2)
  gray = gray.reshape(1,img_rows, img_cols,1)
  gray /= 255
  gray = np.dot(images2[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
  plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
  plt.show()
  model = load_model("first_test")
  # predict digit
  prediction = model.predict(gray)
  print(prediction.argmax())
```

Comment: I was able to fix it like this, any other recommendation? thank you for the once that tried to help me

Answer (score 4):

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Python list doesn't support `..., :3` slicing. It's numpy array feature.
Convert your `image` list to `np.array` first:

```
...
images.append(img)
images = np.array(images)
...
```